# Не подключается к серверному сокету (Android)

Tags: android, сокет, клиент-сервер, сокеты, клиент

Не создается, тост не выполняется

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String ip;
    int port;

    Socket fromServer;
    SocketConnectionTask socketConnection;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        ip = extras.getString("ip");
        port = extras.getInt("port");
        socketConnection = new SocketConnectionTask(this);
        socketConnection.execute(ip, String.valueOf(port));
    }
}


class SocketConnectionTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    Context context;
    Socket fromServer;

    public SocketConnectionTask(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }


    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        InetAddress address;
        try {
            address = InetAddress.getByName(params[0]);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            return false;
        }
        try {
            fromServer = new Socket(address, Integer.parseInt(params[1])); //Тут не переходит на следующие брейкпоиты
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return false; //Этот
        }
        return true; // И этот
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
        boolean b = aBoolean;
        Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(b), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Сервер написан на `Java`. Есть также клиент на `Java` но он подключается к нему почему-то только в локальной сети.

Comment: Что-нибудь есть в logcat?

Comment: @AleksG нет, пусто

Comment: Такое чувство, что он не может подключиться и у него огромный таймаут. Минуты 3 ждал - ничего

Comment: @AleksG Поставил. logcat молчит. Поставил 2 брейкпоинта на `catch` и `return true` не ловит. Так дебаггер дальше строки создания сокета и не идет

Comment: Поставьте брейкпоинт на строчку, где создается сокет.

Comment: @AleksG А вот, `java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /5.100.111.141 (port 9999) after 90000ms`

Comment: Ага, понятно.  В таком случае, нужно просто указать socket timout при соединении.  Сейчас запостаю ответ.

Comment: Подключение к интернету на android устройстве стабильное?

Comment: @KirillStoianov Да, уже в чате ниже все решили. Я не тот IP вставлял. Но работает все равно только в сети локальной, смысла программы больше нет

Comment: Если работает в сети, значит выделенного IP нет.

Answer (score 1):

Основываясь на комментариях, соединение не может быть установлено, а Андроид пытается это сделать в течение длительного времени (90 секунд?).  Чтобы решить эту проблему, нужно указать timeout:

```
fromServer = new Socket();  
SocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress(ip, port); 
fromServer.connect(address, timeout);
```

С этим кодом, он будет пытаться не более 5 секунд.

Comment: Нет такого метода

Comment: Чтобы указать таймаут нужно использовать метод setSoTimeout(int ms); но его нельзя применить до создания объекта класса Socket. Поэтому я не знаю как указать таймаут

Comment: @Herrgott Хм... Андроидная версия сокета не содержит `connect` с тремя параметрами (в яве она есть).  Сейчас поищу.

Comment: `fromServer = new Socket();  
            SocketAddress address1 = new InetSocketAddress(address, Integer.parseInt(params[1]));
            fromServer.connect(address1, 5000);`

Comment: @Herrgott Ага, именно к этому я и пришел :) - исправил в ответе

Comment: Да, но все-же почему он не подключается к серверу?

Comment: Попробуйте из консоли: `telnet your-host your-port` - и проверьте, получается ли подключиться.

Comment: я проверял. Не дождался таймаута

Comment: Значит, проблемы на том сервере - только и всего.  Вы уверены, что там что-нибудь слушает на указанном порте?  Все, что я вижу, указывает на firewall rule 'drop'

Comment: Если подключаться из клиента десктопного, то подключается только по 0.0.0.0 по порту 9999 (Сам указал на сервере)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39396/discussion-between-aleks-g-and-herrgott).